# CircleImage keeps changing colour after selecting an option in picker and adding to list

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-foreach

I'm having this weird issue where the colour for an item in a list changes when a new item with a different colour is added, essentially it doesn't retain its colour-value but takes up a new one.
What I'm trying to do is to show a colour that corresponds to the priority level the user has selected.

Here is the code:

```
struct PriorityGreen: View {
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
            .foregroundColor(Color.green)
    }
}

struct PriorityYellow: View {
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
            .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
    }
}

struct PriorityOrange: View {
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
            .foregroundColor(Color.orange)
    }
}

struct PriorityRed: View {
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
    }
}
```

Code for view

```
import SwiftUI

struct AppView: View {
    @ObservedObject var data = Model()

    @State var showViewTwo = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(data.arrayOfTask, id: \.self) { row in
                        HStack {
                            if self.data.priority == 0 {
                                PriorityGreen()
                            } else if self.data.priority == 1 {
                                PriorityYellow()
                            } else if self.data.priority == 2 {
                                PriorityOrange()
                            } else if self.data.priority == 3 {
                                PriorityRed()
                            }
                            Text("\(row)")
                        }
                    }
                        .onDelete(perform: removeItems).animation(.default)
                }
                    .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
                    .environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .regular)
            }
                .navigationBarTitle("Tasks")
                .navigationBarItems(leading:
                        EditButton().animation(.default),
                    trailing: Button(action: {
                        self.showViewTwo.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("New task")
                    }.sheet(isPresented: $showViewTwo) {
                        ViewTwo(data: self.data, showViewTwo: self.$showViewTwo)
                    })
        }
    }



    func removeItems(at offset: IndexSet) {
        data.arrayOfTask.remove(atOffsets: offset)
    }
}

struct AppView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AppView()
    }
}

struct ViewTwo: View {
    @State var data: Model
    @State var newName = ""
    @State var newCatergory = ""
    @State var newPriorityLevel = ""

    @State var defaultPriorityLevel = 1
    @State var priorityTypes = ["low", "medium", "high", "critical"]


    @Binding var showViewTwo: Bool
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Add task name")) {

                    TextField("Name", text: $newName)
                    /*
                    This section will be implementated later on
                    TextField("Catergory", text: $newCatergory)
                    */
                }
                Section(header: Text("Select task priority")) {
                    Picker("Priority Levels", selection: $defaultPriorityLevel) {
                        ForEach(0..<priorityTypes.count) {
                            Text(self.priorityTypes[$0])
                        }
                    }
                        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                }
            }
                .navigationBarTitle("New task details")
                .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                        Button("Save") {
                            self.showViewTwo.toggle()
                            self.data.taskName = self.newName
                            self.data.arrayOfTask.append(self.newName)
                            self.data.priority = self.defaultPriorityLevel
                    })
        }
    }
}

struct PriorityCirleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
            .foregroundColor(Color.green)
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

enum Catergory {
    case work
    case home
    case family
    case health
    case bills
}

enum Priority {
    case low
    case medium
    case high
    case critical
}



class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var taskName = ""
    @Published var taskCategory = ""
    @Published var priority = 0

    @Published var arrayOfTask = [String]()
}
```

This gif demonstrates the problem more clearly

(Gif)[https://imgur.com/a/ffzpSft]

Comment: Added model to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one priority in your model instead of a priority per task.

Change your model to this:

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    struct Task {
        var taskName = ""
        var taskCategory = ""
        var priority = 0
    }

    @Published var arrayOfTask = [Task]()
}
```

And update your code to use the new model:

```
struct AppView: View {
    @ObservedObject var data = Model()

    @State var showViewTwo = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(data.arrayOfTask, id: \.taskName) { task in
                        HStack {
                            if task.priority == 0 {
                                PriorityGreen()
                            } else if task.priority == 1 {
                                PriorityYellow()
                            } else if task.priority == 2 {
                                PriorityOrange()
                            } else if task.priority == 3 {
                                PriorityRed()
                            }
                            Text("\(task.taskName)")
                        }
                    }
                        .onDelete(perform: removeItems).animation(.default)
                }
                    .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
                    .environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .regular)
            }
                .navigationBarTitle("Tasks")
                .navigationBarItems(leading:
                        EditButton().animation(.default),
                    trailing: Button(action: {
                        self.showViewTwo.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("New task")
                    }.sheet(isPresented: $showViewTwo) {
                        ViewTwo(data: self.data, showViewTwo: self.$showViewTwo)
                    })
        }
    }



    func removeItems(at offset: IndexSet) {
        data.arrayOfTask.remove(atOffsets: offset)
    }
}

struct ViewTwo: View {
    @State var data: Model
    @State var newName = ""
    @State var newCatergory = ""
    @State var newPriorityLevel = ""

    @State var defaultPriorityLevel = 1
    @State var priorityTypes = ["low", "medium", "high", "critical"]


    @Binding var showViewTwo: Bool
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Add task name")) {

                    TextField("Name", text: $newName)
                    /*
                    This section will be implementated later on
                    TextField("Catergory", text: $newCatergory)
                    */
                }
                Section(header: Text("Select task priority")) {
                    Picker("Priority Levels", selection: $defaultPriorityLevel) {
                        ForEach(0..<priorityTypes.count) {
                            Text(self.priorityTypes[$0])
                        }
                    }
                        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                }
            }
                .navigationBarTitle("New task details")
                .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                        Button("Save") {
                            var task = Model.Task()
                            self.showViewTwo.toggle()
                            task.taskName = self.newName
                            task.priority = self.defaultPriorityLevel
                            self.data.arrayOfTask.append(task)
                    })
        }
    }
}
```

---

Using the `taskName` as the `id` is not a good idea.  Update your `Task` struct to include a unique value:

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    struct Task: Identifiable {
        static var uniqueID = 0
        var taskName = ""
        var taskCategory = ""
        var priority = 0
        var id = 0
        
        init() {
            Task.uniqueID += 1
            self.id = Task.uniqueID
        }
    }

    @Published var arrayOfTask = [Task]()
}
```

And then change:

```
ForEach(data.arrayOfTask, id: \.taskName) { task in
```

to

```
ForEach(data.arrayOfTask) { task in
```

Comment: Thank you for you response, the code now works as intended, I will try to better understand it first thing in the morning. Once again thank you.

Comment: Check my update.  The code was using the `taskName` as the `id` which meant 2 tasks with the same name would display the same priority.  I made `Task` `Identifiable` and added a unique `id` value to it.